# How to use side-nav from materialize in vue.js 2.0

Tags: vue.js, materialize, vuejs2

I am creating a vue.js app which I want to style with materialize. I appear to have got it all installed without errors but I have no functionality, specifically for the sideNav. What I mean is when I click the menu icon, nothing happens.

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
...
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.js"></script>
...
```

**main.js**

```
import Materials from 'vue-materials'
Vue.use(Materials)
```

**.vue file**

```
<v-side-nav id="side-nav" class="right hide-on-small">
    <li><a v-on:click="handleLogout()">Logout</a></li>
</v-side-nav>
```

Everything looks ok, just no pop-out menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to have `v-btn-link` on click on which this will come up, as it is given in [demo](http://johnleider.com/vue-materials-docs/):

```
<v-btn-link v-side-nav:demo="nav">Click Me</v-btn-link>
<v-side-nav id="demo">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="n in 5">
            <a href="#!">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</v-side-nav>


export default {
    data () {
        return {
            nav: {
                edge: 'right'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was working from the Directive page so I totally missed the demo. Thanks

Comment: This works but the v-btn-link element is adding a btn class. Any chance I can stop that happening?

Comment: @khany Can you create a fiddle of it, so that experimenting becomes easy.